# How to capture the names of all files read and written by an R script?

Tags: r

In a project, many separate scripts are executed and they read and write files from / for each other. It has become quite confusing, which file is coming from where. Of course, this is bad software design but that is how this has grown over a long time.

Now, I would to execute all scripts in their proper order and capture which files are read and which ones are written by each script.

Is there, e.g., a way to monitor and log the input and output of the R process while the script is running (from within R)? Or any other ideas for a solution?
I am running R under Windows 10.

Comment: Namespaces are a good thing. Just make directories and output files like `out/script_1/result1.png`

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely a doable option. However, a more automatic way would be even better.